# How to sum all rather than just distinct values in clingo?

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

The following code produces `x(3)` rather than `x(4)` because it adds 1 and 2 together even though 1 appears twice. What is the right way of obtaining *total* sums in clingo?

```
p(0,1;1,1;2,2).
x(X) :- X = #sum { Y: p(_,Y) }.
```

Answer (score 1):

Still not quite sure why this works but it does:

```
x(X) :- X = #sum { Y, Z: p(Z,Y) }.
```

So, it seems you have to write out the entire "unique key" but only the first value is summed up. I don't this explained or even mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: It is explained exactly like this in the documentation.
The #sum aggregate sums up a SET of TUPLES. This is why your unary tuple "1" was only counted once. The actual weight of the tuple is its first element. So you did everything correct.
https://github.com/potassco/guide/releases/download/v2.2.0/guide.pdf Section 3.1.12